# IDA Pro failed to display the program in graph mode

Tags: ida, unpacking

i am a complete beginner with IDA and I have just tried to follow a tutorial on how to unpack UPX.

In the tutorial IDA looks like this:

[image]

When I try to get the graphical view like in the tutorial an error message appears:

[image]

I cannot find the Names window too, please help me.

Here is how IDA Pro looks like at the moment:

**https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWAQa.png**

Version: IDA Pro 6.5

Sorry for those noob questions, but I am confused.

Comment: I know you are learning  ida, but use ida for unpack/dynamic reverse (my experience) is not good idea.

Answer (score 5):

IDA can only display functions in graphical mode if they have a well-defined start and end address. Normally, the start and end address are determined from the disassembly - the start address is the target address of `call` instructions, the end address is where the code has a `ret` instruction (*).

In your case, IDA failed to make a function from your code, probably because there is no call to `start`, and maybe there's not even a `ret` at the end. You can try to fix that by moving the cursor to the `start` label and pressing the `P` key. Once your code is defined as a function, the space key should switch between graphical view and assembly view just like your tutorial says.

(*) Actually, it's a bit more complicated; some parts of the function may be behind the `ret`; but IDA detects this from jumps within the function.

Comment: Pressing the "p" key on EP results in: `UPX1:00486DA3: The function has undefined instruction/data at the specified address.
Your request has been put in the autoanalysis queue.` Thank you for your answer so far, interesting!

Comment: This means that IDA can't define the function. Probably since it is not yet fully unpacked.

Answer (score -1):

I realize this is very old, but in most cases this is solved easily - check if you are under a procedure context, for example if you searched for a string value then go to the place the label is used (pressing x) and then it will show the graphical view